# Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name

Tags: ajax, fetch

simple website contact submit code using fetch sending formdata to api.
the fetch method returns'Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name' error in console, meanwhile XMLHttpRequest works.
How can i fix the fetch method?

```
contactForm.addEventListener('submit', async function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // console.log('clicked');

  const formData = {
    name: formName.value,
    email: formEmail.value,
    tel: formTel.value,
    message: formMessage.value,
  };

  // FIXME
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });

    return response.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }

  // XMLHttp methode works
  // let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // xhr.open('POST', '/');
  // xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  // xhr.onload = function () {
  //   if (xhr.responseText === 'success') {
  //     //add a popout window

  //     formName.value = '';
  //     formEmail.value = '';
  //     formTel.value = '';
  //     message.value = '';
  //   } else {
  //     alert('Something went wrong!');
  //   }
  // };
  // xhr.send(JSON.stringify(formData));
});
```

Comment: What browser are you testing this is?

Comment: Does the error message really say `Window` with a capital W?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://jsbin.com/vimajutosa/1/edit?html,js,output